# Limit frequency with which firestore retrieves data

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using swift and Firestore and in my application I have a snapshotlistener which retrieves data every time some documents are changed. As I expect this to happen many times a second, I would like to limit the snapshotlistener to retrieve data once every 2 seconds, say. Is this possible? I looked everywhere but could not find anything.

Comment: The question is counterintuitive. Adding a snapshotListener to a node is designed to present changes to your app in a real-time, event driven way. If you want to get data every two seconds, that's more of a *polling* strategy and defeats the purpose of a listener. If you want polling then don't add a listener at all and just read the nodes you want every two seconds. The bigger question is why don't you want real-time data since you selected a real-time database? What's the challenge with using events as they come in?

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Firestore stores your data in multiple data centers, and only confirms the write operations once it's written to all of those. For this reason the maximum update frequency of a single document in Cloud Firestore is roughly once per second. So if your plan is to update a document many times per second, that won't work anyway.

---

There is no way to set a limit on how frequently Firestore broadcasts out updates to the underlying data. If the data gets updated, it is broadcast out to all active listeners.

The typical solution would be to limit how frequently you update the data. If nobody is going to see a significant chunk of the updates, you might as well not *write* them to the database. This sort of logic if often accomplished with a client side throttle/debounce (see [1](https://github.com/malcommac/Repeat), [2](https://gist.github.com/simme/b78d10f0b29325743a18c905c5512788)).