# Cloud Firestore throttling high-volume update syncing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

(Note: sorry if I am using the relational DB terms here.)

Let's say I have ten clients that are connected to a database. This database has a sustained throughput of about 1k updates per second. Obviously sending 1k updates per second to a web-browser (let's say 1MB data changes per second) is not going to be a good experience for the end-user. Does Firebase have any controls as to how much data a client can 'accept' before it starts throttling it? I understand it may batch requests, but my point here is, Google can accept data/updates faster than a browser can (potentially from a phone on a weak internet connection), so what controls or techniques are there in place to control this experience for the end-user?

The only items I see from the docs are:

> You should not update a single document more than once per second. If you update a document too quickly, then your application will experience contention, including higher latency, timeouts, and other errors.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#updates_to_a_single_document

Answer (score 0):

This topic is covered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56714507/limit-frequency-with-which-firestore-retrieves-data), keeping the language used to code in aside, the linked code in that answer can assist.

In a general explanation, if your client application is configured to listen for Firestore updates, it will receive all the update events to that listener (just like you mentioned is happening).

You can consider polling Firebase for changes. The poll can even be an extension of the client application code where the code tracks the frequency of the updates being received and has a maximum value of updates per second which, when reached, results in the client disconnecting as a listener and performing periodic polls for the data.
The listener could then be re-established after a period to continue the normal workflow when there are fewer updates again.

The above being said, this is not optimal and treats the symptom rather than the cause. If a listener is returning too many updates, you should consider the structure of the data and look to isolate the updates to only require updates to listeners that require it.

Similarly, the large updates can be mitigated by ensuring smaller records contain the changes resulting in less data.
A generalized example is where two fields of data are updated, but the record is 150 fields in size. Rather than returning the full 150 fields, shard the fields into different data sets, so the two fields are in their own record with an additional reference field used to correlate with a second data set of the remaining 148 fields (plus the reference field).
When the smaller record is updated, the client application receives the small update, determines if the update is applicable to itself, and if so, fetches the corresponding larger record.

Comment: looks like you forget to add a link at the first line `This topic is covered in [1]` or last link is one ? please update.

Comment: The last link is the one. Let me edit it for better readability and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent high volumes of writes from overwhelming the client's snapshot listeners, you could **periodically duplicate the writes to a proxy collection that the client watches instead**.

Documents would need a field to record the time of the last duplicate write to the proxy collection, and the process performing the writes should avoid making writes to the proxy collection until after the frequency duration has elapsed.

A small number of unnecessary writes may still occur due to any concurrent processes you have, but these might be insignificant in practice (with a reasonably long duplication frequency).

If the data belongs to a user, rather than being global data, then you could conceivably **adjust the frequency of writes per user to suit their connection**, either dynamically or based on user configuration.

In this way, your processes get to control the frequency of writes seen by clients, without needing to throttle or otherwise reject ingress writes (which would presumably be bad news for the upstream processes).

Relevant part of the documentation below.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#realtime_updates

> Limit the collection write rate
> 1,000 operations/second
>
> Keep the rate of write operations for an individual collection under 1,000 operations/second.
>
> Limit the individual client push rate
> 1 document/second
>
> Keep the rate of documents the database pushes to an individual client under 1 document/second.